# Custom directive to detect out side the button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to write a custom directive to close (or hide) the button when click out side the button (empty area of the DOM). In other words anywhere except within the button ? This behaviour should be applied only for this button when I apply the custom directive.Any guide would be highly appreciated.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="CreateUpdate()">Submit</button>

app.directive('MyDirective', function() {
       //content
});
```

Comment: Any guide? What have you tried that didn't work? I am sure you are aware that questions on StackOverflow are not supposed to be requests for code?

Comment: @Patrick Problem which I have is where I don't know how to approach this ?

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to click on other things as well, or is "a click outside" only supposed to hide the button and nothing else?

Comment: You *can* solve this by using an overlay with fixed position at (0,0) and width, height set to 100%; if you click that, you hide the button.

Comment: @Patrick click anywhere on the DOM. Definitely not an other buttons or like that ? Just a empty area ?

Comment: Depending on your HTML, you can probably solve this in css as well, using the :focus-selector

Comment: So you're not *allowed* to click on other buttons, but everything else should have a click event handler that hides the button?

Comment: @Patrick I would like to go with the directive hence I can use it again some where else.

Comment: @Patrick There is no such restriction.I just need to hide the button when it clicks empty space on the DOM.

Comment: I understand that, but there's details missing as to how you would solve this. It would be easier to help you if you narrow down the details, otherwise you might get answers that are "correct" but you would consider them incorrect because they don't do exactly what you want

Comment: Then my follow-up question is; what do you define as empty space in the DOM? Would an overlay with a click-handler solve your problem?

Comment: And also, if you click another button, what is supposed to happen? Should the button not be hidden in that case?

Comment: @Patrick only for this button.

Comment: @Patrick When I apply my custom directive to that button,it should work as I mentioned above.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angularjs

Comment: @Yoggi Then what's your solution ?

Comment: It's javascript related. Tons of people have already answered similar questions. E.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: @Yoggi I'm not using jquery.I need to write an angular directive for that functionality.

Comment: However, angular uses jqLite if you haven't included Jquery in your project. Also, there are plenty of plain javascript solutions out there. As I sad, this is not a angular related issue.

Comment: @Yoggi I have written an angular directive.I'll update here later.

Answer (score 0):

Within the button directive you can inject $document. Then wire up on click on the document.

```
<button class="myButton btn btn-primary" ng--lick="CreateUpdate()">Submit</button>

mainModule.directive("myButton", ['$document',
    function ($document) {
         return {
             restrict: "E",
             link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                       $document.bind('click', function(event){
                       //Get the element clicked
                       var clickedElement = angular.element(event.target);
                       // If the clickedElement is not same as button (say, the clicked element class is different from button class) then close the button.
                   }
                }
           })
```